# Unauthorized even when middleware return AuthenticateResult.Success

Tags: c#, authentication, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created a middleware that configures authentication using JWT token. 
In startup.cs -

```
services.AddAuthentication(BearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMyBearer(opt =>
            {
                opt.TokenValidationUrl = Configuration[SettingsKey.ApiBaseUri] + "/oauth/validatetoken?version=1";
                opt.UserTokenCookieName = Configuration[SettingsKey.UserTokenCookieName];
                opt.SubscriptionKey = Configuration[SettingsKey.SubscriptionKey];
                opt.Issuer = Configuration[SettingsKey.ApplicationUID];
                opt.AuthorizeAllRequests = Convert.ToBoolean(Configuration[SettingsKey.AuthorizeAllRequests]);
                opt.AuthenticationScheme = BearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            });
```

The extension class contains the following code -

```
return authBuilder.AddScheme<AuthenticationOptions, AuthHandler>(BearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, configureOptions);
```

Below is the return part in the `HandleAuthenticateAsync` method-

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
AuthenticationTicket authenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Options.AuthenticationScheme);
return AuthenticateResult.Success(authenticationTicket);
```

I have verified that the claims list contains all the required claims breakpoint on the `return AuthenticateResult.Success` also hits. However, even after this, the controller returns Unauthorized when decorated with `[Authorize]` attribute.

Comment: Have you placed `app.UseAuthentication();` before `app.UseMvc()`? Is there any demo to reproduce your issue?

Comment: @TaoZhou yes UseMvc is the last middleware in my pipeline

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue?

Comment: actually due to company policy, i can't share any more of the code. Actually the issue has also been resolved. I will put up and answer soon. Thing is claims identity doesn't set the `IsAuthenticated` property to True. I used `new GenericIdentity` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the `ClaimsIdentity` didn't set the `IsAuthenticated` property of the Identity as True. Instead of that i had to use `GenericIdentity()` and add the claims later. This approach worked fine.